# Jquery mScroller not working on angular Js app

Tags: angularjs

```
$(".blueScrollBox").mCustomScrollbar({
    snapAmount: 40,
    scrollButtons: {enable: true},
    keyboard: {scrollAmount: 40},
    mouseWheel: {deltaFactor: 40},
    scrollInertia: 400
});
```

The above is the mScroller jquery call i am using in an angular app , so its not working all the time , sometimes working and sometimes not.

Comment: you need to wrap jQuery code inside directive.. as you need wait till angular creates a DOM..

Comment: so i need to create a directive for this and use that directive.

Comment: yes..you need to wrap this code inside directive link function..

Comment: http://henriquat.re/directives/advanced-directives-combining-angular-with-existing-components-and-jquery/angularAndJquery.html   like the above